# Place pictures and text in html page

Tags: html, css, image

I have simple page with text and images in it. Like this:
HTML

```
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT1</p>
<div id='image'></div>
<p>text2</p>
```

CSS

```
div#image
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: url("../image/image.png") no-repeat 0 0; 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 1210px;
    top: 650px;

}
```

This look differen in different browsers. So this is bad way. Images should be near to text. Is it possible to place divs with `image` and `p` relatively?

Like in [image: picture]

**UPDATE According to answer:**
CSS

```
div.imageWithTexts
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  vertical-align: top
}
div.imageWithTexts img
{
width:100%
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='imageWithTexts'>text</div>
<div class='imageWithTexts'><img></img></div>
<div class='imageWithTexts'>text</div>
```

Looks like [image: this]

Comment: For Images there is usually the `img` tag. Also, in your HTML code the ID of your DIV is `image`, while in the CSS code it's `aboutImage1`.

Comment: Yep, my mistake with IDs.I've copied css id from my code. Is it a big differnce between div and img? How can I place img at certainc place without absolute positioning?

Comment: Don't really understand what second minus for. I've edited my mistake in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want based on your image

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  vertical-align: top
}
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/20/03/43/400_F_20034366_DPxCA1ryMUc73AcDi3u0WU6HUX94i8Rl.jpg " />
</div>
<div>test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/20/03/43/400_F_20034366_DPxCA1ryMUc73AcDi3u0WU6HUX94i8Rl.jpg " />
</div>
```

See Full Page Result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158774/place-pictures-and-text-in-html-page/26159063#26159063)

**UPDATED ANSWER with OP new code**:

the snippet still works:

```css
div.imageWithTexts {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  vertical-align: top
}
div.imageWithTexts img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class='imageWithTexts'>text</div>
<div class='imageWithTexts'>
  <img src="http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/20/03/43/400_F_20034366_DPxCA1ryMUc73AcDi3u0WU6HUX94i8Rl.jpg " />
</div>
<div class='imageWithTexts'>text</div>
```

Comment: And how can I place div in certain places without absolute postioning? Sory I wrote wrong id in my code.

Comment: where you want to put it?

Comment: I gonna paint a picture.=)

Comment: Look in picture, I've attached.

Comment: updated answer, take a look

Comment: I gonna test it and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Itn's not working as I want. Look my update.

Comment: Also I have <p> tags in my divs can it cause problem?

Comment: Removed p tags. Result is the same.

Comment: updated answer, your code works, you may have anything around wrapping with padding maybe? can you show the link to website?

Answer (score 1):

Based on first picture you posted, if you want to center the img verticaly, you can use vertical-align css property.

```css
.row div{
    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
      <img src="yourImage1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel molestie mi. Maecenas pulvinar nibh orci, vel volutpat nulla suscipit quis. Suspendisse felis augue, placerat nec neque sit amet, suscipit molestie odio. Aliquam lorem leo, semper a libero non, luctus tristique tortor. Maecenas pretium a ligula in semper.
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="yourImage2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to center it. I want to place it like in my first picture.

Comment: Alright, just remove vertical-align property then.

Answer (score 0):

In my case inline-block overlaps by padding or something else. It was not my own design so I had to put `<img align='left' src='path/image.png'>` to put pricture on left.